# Manipulation of data with BASH

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file full of lines like the following:

```
8408292236 48.04 46n20.13  12e43.22   1.00  3.1  MCSTI  0.4897 108  0.10  0.10  20  41 84EV01978
```

The first two digits in the first column represent the year and I need to substitute them with the full year while retaining the full line. I tried various method with awk and sed but couldn't get them working.

My latest attempt is the following:

```
while read line
a=20 
b=19
do
    awk '{ if ("$1 | cut -c1-2" == "0"); then {print $a$1}; }' > test.txt
done < catalog.txt
```

The final output should be:

```
198408292236 48.04 46n20.13  12e43.22   1.00  3.1  MCSTI  0.4897 108  0.10  0.10  20  41 84EV01978
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: okay, you want to prefix 19 or 20. When do you want to prefix 19 and when 20?

Comment: When the first two digits are less than 15, prefix 20, else prefix 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prefix 19 if the first field starts with 16 or more, and will prefix 20 otherwise.  I think this is what you need.

```
awk ' { if ($1 > 1600000000 ) print "19" $0 ; else print "20" $0 ;  }' catalog.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a conceptional problem. How would you know whether 15 refers to 2015 or 1915. Otherwise it's quite easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
for num in 8408292236 8508292236 0408292236 1508292236
do
    prefix=${num:0:2} # get first two digits of line
    if [ $prefix -ge 20 ]; then # assuming that 0-20 refers to the 2000s 
        echo "19$num"
    else 
        echo "20$num"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/^[0-3]/20\0/' -e 's/^[4-9]/19\0/'
```

This will append 19 to each line starting with 3 to 9 or 20 to each line starting with 0 to 2, so we consider 30 - 99 to correspond to 1900, and 00-29 to correspond to 2000.

Adapt to your need.

Comment: You missed the capturing parenthesis... `sed -e 's/^([4-9])/19\1/' -e 's/^([0-3])/20\1/'`... Else, replace `\1` with `&`...

Comment: Also, you need to swap the order of 2 matching rules. After first rule is run, second rule would match (since the string now starts with `19`, which matches `[0-3]`).

Comment: @anishsane I meant to use the `\0` referring to the whole matched string, thanks for making me notice my mistake. Good catch for the execution order too

Comment: Oh, I did not know about `\0`... I used `&` for that... New lesson for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` *ternary* operator.

```
$ cat catalog.txt
8408292236 48.04 46n20.13  12e43.22   1.00  3.1  MCSTI  0.4897 108  0.10  0.10  20  41 84EV01978
0408292236 48.04 46n20.13  12e43.22   1.00  3.1  MCSTI  0.4897 108  0.10  0.10  20  41 84EV01978

$ awk '$1=substr($1,1,2)<15 ? "20"$1 : "19"$1' catalog.txt
198408292236 48.04 46n20.13 12e43.22 1.00 3.1 MCSTI 0.4897 108 0.10 0.10 20 41 84EV01978
200408292236 48.04 46n20.13 12e43.22 1.00 3.1 MCSTI 0.4897 108 0.10 0.10 20 41 84EV01978
```

**Explanation**

Let’s use the ternary operator.

```
expr ? action1 : action2
```

Its pretty straight forward: if `expr`is true then `action1` is performed/evaluated , if not `action2`.

Field one must be prefixed with `19` or `20` depending of it's two first chars value `substr($1,1,2)`.

*NOTE*: This only works if your data does not contains years bellow `1915`.

At this point, we just need to change the first field `$1` to our needs: `$1=substr($1,1,2)<15 ? "20"$1 : "19"$1`

Check: http://klashxx.github.io/ternary-operator/

Answer (score 1):

A solution using just bash:

```
 while read A; do
    PREFIX=20
    if  [ ${A:0:2} -gt 15 ] ; then
       PREFIX=19
    fi
    echo "${PREFIX}${A}"
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply in `bash`:

```
while read i; do echo "$((${i:0:2}<20?20:19))$i"; done <file.txt
```

shorter in `perl`:

```
perl -pe'print substr($_,0,2)<20?20:19' file.txt
```

even shorter in `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[01]/20&/;t;s/^/19/' file.txt
```